My glmer output has my fixed effects are being split into the multiple factors of my dependant variables and I'm not sure why
I am being advised that the output for my GLMER model is not correct. I at this time am not being given more instruction outside of that.
To set up the data for analysis, the following was done to partition the code and group the data into what would best answer our research questions.

Do melanophores affect visual acuity in larval zebrafish?
Do iridophores affect visual acuity in larval zebrafish?

The data has to be formatted with the following steps. Below is where we gather the responses to the grating frequencies, separate them from the acclimation data, and give them their binary scores.
LarvalOMRPigment1 <- LarvalOMRPigment1 #step 1

LarvalOMRPigment1 <- LarvalOMRPigment1 %>%
  gather(key = "frequency_pigment", value = "response_pg", `grating_1`, `grating_2`, 
         `grating_3`, `grating_4`, `grating_5`, `grating_6`, `grating_7` ) #step 2

LarvalOMRPigment1 <- LarvalOMRPigment1 %>%
  gather(key = "frequency_acclimation", value = "response_ac", `acclimation`) #step 2.5

#Acclimation was removed because it was reducing differences between the subjects 
#Acclimation will now have its own column to do independent sample T-test

LarvalOMRPigment1$OMRResponse <- LarvalOMRPigment1$response_pg #Step 3
LarvalOMRPigment1 <- LarvalOMRPigment1 %>%
  mutate(OMRResponse = if_else(response_pg == "Q4", 1, 0)) #step 4

LarvalOMRPigment1$AcclimationResponse <- LarvalOMRPigment1$response_ac #Step 3.5
LarvalOMRPigment1 <- LarvalOMRPigment1 %>%
  mutate(AcclimationResponse = if_else(response_ac == "Q4", 1, 0)) #step 4.5

The new columns for response to the frequencies being made, we move to making sure our data structure is formatted correctly.
# Make sure all of the structure is correct, most will remain as factors 

LarvalOMRPigment1$strain <- as.factor(LarvalOMRPigment1$strain)
LarvalOMRPigment1$age <- as.factor(LarvalOMRPigment1$age)
LarvalOMRPigment1$subject <- as.factor(LarvalOMRPigment1$subject)
LarvalOMRPigment1$frequency_pigment <- as.factor(LarvalOMRPigment1$frequency_pigment) #run first as factor 
LarvalOMRPigment1$frequency_acclimation <- as.factor(LarvalOMRPigment1$frequency_acclimation) #run first as factor 
LarvalOMRPigment1$transgene <- as.factor(LarvalOMRPigment1$transgene)
LarvalOMRPigment1$AcclimationResponse <- as.factor(LarvalOMRPigment1$AcclimationResponse)
LarvalOMRPigment1$OMRResponse <- as.factor(LarvalOMRPigment1$OMRResponse)
LarvalOMRPigment1$body_pigment <- as.factor(LarvalOMRPigment1$body_pigment)

The frequencies will need to be run as numerics after being run as factors.
LarvalOMRPigment1$frequency_pigment <- as.numeric(LarvalOMRPigment1$frequency_pigment) 
#then run again as a numeric
LarvalOMRPigment1$frequency_acclimation <- as.numeric(LarvalOMRPigment1$frequency_acclimation) 
#then run again as a numeric


This leaves us with the following structure
str(LarvalOMRPigment1)

## tibble [4,200 × 11] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
##  $ strain               : Factor w/ 5 levels "AB","Casper",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
##  $ subject              : Factor w/ 600 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
##  $ age                  : Factor w/ 3 levels "5 DPF","6 DPF",..: 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
##  $ body_pigment         : Factor w/ 4 levels "b","i","m","n": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
##  $ transgene            : Factor w/ 2 levels "n","y": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
##  $ frequency_pigment    : num [1:4200] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
##  $ response_pg          : chr [1:4200] "Q4" "Q4" "Q4" "Q4" ...
##  $ frequency_acclimation: num [1:4200] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
##  $ response_ac          : chr [1:4200] "Q3" "Q4" "Q2" "Q2" ...
##  $ OMRResponse          : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
##  $ AcclimationResponse  : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 ...

After the structure is verified, the data is put into subsets to again better answer the research questions at their specific age group. Below is an example of how this was done for the output provided. This is done for all three age groups and both pigment types. When checking for errors in subsetting, we had to use the print function to make sure that the age groups were being separated because when using the str() function it appears that they are not. This double conformation is done again when subset for pigment types.
subset_5dpf_OMRPigment <- subset(LarvalOMRPigment1, age == "5 DPF")

#Check that the code ran correctly
str(subset_5dpf_OMRPigment)

## tibble [1,400 × 11] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
##  $ strain               : Factor w/ 5 levels "AB","Casper",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
##  $ subject              : Factor w/ 600 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 401 402 403 404 405 406 407 408 409 410 ...
##  $ age                  : Factor w/ 3 levels "5 DPF","6 DPF",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
##  $ body_pigment         : Factor w/ 4 levels "b","i","m","n": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
##  $ transgene            : Factor w/ 2 levels "n","y": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
##  $ frequency_pigment    : num [1:1400] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
##  $ response_pg          : chr [1:1400] "Q4" "Q4" "Q4" "Q4" ...
##  $ frequency_acclimation: num [1:1400] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
##  $ response_ac          : chr [1:1400] "Q4" "Q4" "Q4" "q4" ...
##  $ OMRResponse          : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 2 2 2 1 1 2 1 2 1 ...
##  $ AcclimationResponse  : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...

#confirm that only 5dpf data is being used below

print(subset_5dpf_OMRPigment)

## # A tibble: 1,400 × 11
##    strain subject age   body_pigment transgene frequency_pigment response_pg
##    <fct>  <fct>   <fct> <fct>        <fct>                 <dbl> <chr>      
##  1 AB     401     5 DPF b            n                         1 Q4         
##  2 AB     402     5 DPF b            n                         1 Q4         
##  3 AB     403     5 DPF b            n                         1 Q4         
##  4 AB     404     5 DPF b            n                         1 Q4         
##  5 AB     405     5 DPF b            n                         1 Q1         
##  6 AB     406     5 DPF b            n                         1 Q1         
##  7 AB     407     5 DPF b            n                         1 Q4         
##  8 AB     408     5 DPF b            n                         1 Q3         
##  9 AB     409     5 DPF b            n                         1 Q4         
## 10 AB     410     5 DPF b            n                         1 Q1         
## # ℹ 1,390 more rows
## # ℹ 4 more variables: frequency_acclimation <dbl>, response_ac <chr>,
## #   OMRResponse <fct>, AcclimationResponse <fct>

The following subset is what will make up what we use in the model. We subset for the age and the three strains of zebrafish necessary to answer the pigment question for melanophores. This means that in this group of fish, three out of the four pigment types will be present in the data set; m = only melanophores, b = both pigment types, and n = neither pigment type.
melanophore_OMR_5dpf <- subset(subset_5dpf_OMRPigment, strain %in% c("Roy", "Casper", "AB", age == "5 DPF"))

print(melanophore_OMR_5dpf)

## # A tibble: 840 × 11
##    strain subject age   body_pigment transgene frequency_pigment response_pg
##    <fct>  <fct>   <fct> <fct>        <fct>                 <dbl> <chr>      
##  1 AB     401     5 DPF b            n                         1 Q4         
##  2 AB     402     5 DPF b            n                         1 Q4         
##  3 AB     403     5 DPF b            n                         1 Q4         
##  4 AB     404     5 DPF b            n                         1 Q4         
##  5 AB     405     5 DPF b            n                         1 Q1         
##  6 AB     406     5 DPF b            n                         1 Q1         
##  7 AB     407     5 DPF b            n                         1 Q4         
##  8 AB     408     5 DPF b            n                         1 Q3         
##  9 AB     409     5 DPF b            n                         1 Q4         
## 10 AB     410     5 DPF b            n                         1 Q1         
## # ℹ 830 more rows
## # ℹ 4 more variables: frequency_acclimation <dbl>, response_ac <chr>,
## #   OMRResponse <fct>, AcclimationResponse <fct>


Below is the model that I am using. This is the base for all the age groups I am using and will have a similar design for the other pigment types. Each of my outputs has the same issue with my pigments being broken down into their levels, below is just one example.
melanophore_OMR_5dpf_glmer = glmer(OMRResponse ~ body_pigment*frequency_pigment + (frequency_pigment|subject) , 
  data = melanophore_OMR_5dpf, family = binomial, nAGQ = 1)

## Warning in checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv, :
## Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 0.00623225 (tol = 0.002, component 1)

summary(melanophore_OMR_5dpf_glmer)

## Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace
##   Approximation) [glmerMod]
##  Family: binomial  ( logit )
## Formula: OMRResponse ~ body_pigment * frequency_pigment + (frequency_pigment |  
##     subject)
##    Data: melanophore_OMR_5dpf
## 
##      AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
##   1107.9   1150.5   -545.0   1089.9      831 
## 
## Scaled residuals: 
##     Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
## -1.2506 -0.7616 -0.6018  1.0793  1.7991 
## 
## Random effects:
##  Groups  Name              Variance Std.Dev. Corr 
##  subject (Intercept)       0.28500  0.53385       
##          frequency_pigment 0.00023  0.01517  -1.00
## Number of obs: 840, groups:  subject, 120
## 
## Fixed effects:
##                                 Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
## (Intercept)                      0.69903    0.29485   2.371 0.017749 *  
## body_pigmentm                   -0.62909    0.41501  -1.516 0.129557    
## body_pigmentn                   -1.24161    0.42448  -2.925 0.003444 ** 
## frequency_pigment               -0.22547    0.06440  -3.501 0.000463 ***
## body_pigmentm:frequency_pigment  0.09177    0.09048   1.014 0.310454    
## body_pigmentn:frequency_pigment  0.16349    0.09223   1.773 0.076273 .  
## ---
## Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
## 
## Correlation of Fixed Effects:
##              (Intr) bdy_pgmntm bdy_pgmntn frqnc_ bdy_pgmntm:_
## body_pgmntm  -0.711                                          
## body_pgmntn  -0.698  0.499                                   
## frqncy_pgmn  -0.867  0.615      0.604                        
## bdy_pgmntm:_  0.616 -0.866     -0.432     -0.708             
## bdy_pgmntn:_  0.606 -0.433     -0.867     -0.695  0.497      
## optimizer (Nelder_Mead) convergence code: 0 (OK)
## Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 0.00623225 (tol = 0.002, component 1)

In troubleshooting this, I assumed there might be an issue in how the data was subset, so I fed R the data again with only the necessary information (the information I   would subset out) instead of giving the program the entire master file and partitioning the data for the model. This gave me the same output. The data for this test was structured the same as the master file, however it only contains data from the one age group and three strains of fish.
melanophore_OMR_5dpf_glmerTest = glmer(OMRResponse5dpf ~ body_pigment*frequency_pigment5dpf + (frequency_pigment5dpf|subject) , 
     data = PigmentTest5dpf, family = binomial, nAGQ = 1)

summary(melanophore_OMR_5dpf_glmerTest)

## Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace
##   Approximation) [glmerMod]
##  Family: binomial  ( logit )
## Formula: 
## OMRResponse5dpf ~ body_pigment * frequency_pigment5dpf + (frequency_pigment5dpf |  
##     subject)
##    Data: PigmentTest5dpf
## 
##      AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
##   1107.9   1150.5   -545.0   1089.9      831 
## 
## Scaled residuals: 
##     Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
## -1.2506 -0.7616 -0.6018  1.0793  1.7991 
## 
## Random effects:
##  Groups  Name                  Variance Std.Dev. Corr 
##  subject (Intercept)           0.28500  0.53385       
##          frequency_pigment5dpf 0.00023  0.01517  -1.00
## Number of obs: 840, groups:  subject, 120
## 
## Fixed effects:
##                                     Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
## (Intercept)                          0.69903    0.29485   2.371 0.017749 *  
## body_pigmentm                       -0.62909    0.41501  -1.516 0.129557    
## body_pigmentn                       -1.24161    0.42448  -2.925 0.003444 ** 
## frequency_pigment5dpf               -0.22547    0.06440  -3.501 0.000463 ***
## body_pigmentm:frequency_pigment5dpf  0.09177    0.09048   1.014 0.310454    
## body_pigmentn:frequency_pigment5dpf  0.16349    0.09223   1.773 0.076273 .  
## ---
## Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
## 
## Correlation of Fixed Effects:
##               (Intr) bdy_pgmntm bdy_pgmntn frqn_5 bdy_pgmntm:_5
## body_pgmntm   -0.711                                           
## body_pgmntn   -0.698  0.499                                    
## frqncy_pgm5   -0.867  0.615      0.604                         
## bdy_pgmntm:_5  0.616 -0.866     -0.432     -0.708              
## bdy_pgmntn:_5  0.606 -0.433     -0.867     -0.695  0.497       
## optimizer (Nelder_Mead) convergence code: 0 (OK)
## Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 0.00623225 (tol = 0.002, component 1)

Below is the data needed to run this code.
structure(list(
    strain = c("AB","AB","AB","AB","AB","AB","AB","AB","AB","AB","AB","AB","AB","AB","AB","AB","AB","AB","AB","AB","AB","AB","AB","AB","AB","AB","AB","AB","AB","AB","AB","AB","AB","AB","AB","AB","AB","AB","AB","AB","Casper","Casper","Casper","Casper","Casper","Casper","Casper","Casper","Casper","Casper","Casper","Casper","Casper","Casper","Casper","Casper","Casper","Casper","Casper","Casper","Casper","Casper","Casper","Casper","Casper","Casper","Casper","Casper","Casper","Casper","Casper","Casper","Casper","Casper","Casper","Casper","Casper","Casper","Casper","Casper","Roy","Roy","Roy","Roy","Roy","Roy","Roy","Roy","Roy","Roy","Roy","Roy","Roy","Roy","Roy","Roy","Roy","Roy","Roy","Roy","Roy","Roy","Roy","Roy","Roy","Roy","Roy","Roy","Roy","Roy","Roy","Roy","Roy","Roy","Roy","Roy","Roy","Roy","Roy","Roy","Nacre","Nacre","Nacre","Nacre","Nacre","Nacre","Nacre","Nacre","Nacre","Nacre","Nacre","Nacre","Nacre","Nacre","Nacre","Nacre","Nacre","Nacre","Nacre","Nacre","Nacre","Nacre","Nacre","Nacre","Nacre","Nacre","Nacre","Nacre","Nacre","Nacre","Nacre","Nacre","Nacre","Nacre","Nacre","Nacre","Nacre","Nacre","Nacre","Nacre","Tg(hsp70l:EGFP+)","Tg(hsp70l:EGFP+)","Tg(hsp70l:EGFP+)","Tg(hsp70l:EGFP+)","Tg(hsp70l:EGFP+)","Tg(hsp70l:EGFP+)","Tg(hsp70l:EGFP+)","Tg(hsp70l:EGFP+)","Tg(hsp70l:EGFP+)","Tg(hsp70l:EGFP+)","Tg(hsp70l:EGFP+)","Tg(hsp70l:EGFP+)","Tg(hsp70l:EGFP+)","Tg(hsp70l:EGFP+)","Tg(hsp70l:EGFP+)","Tg(hsp70l:EGFP+)","Tg(hsp70l:EGFP+)","Tg(hsp70l:EGFP+)","Tg(hsp70l:EGFP+)","Tg(hsp70l:EGFP+)","Tg(hsp70l:EGFP+)","Tg(hsp70l:EGFP+)","Tg(hsp70l:EGFP+)","Tg(hsp70l:EGFP+)","Tg(hsp70l:EGFP+)","Tg(hsp70l:EGFP+)","Tg(hsp70l:EGFP+)","Tg(hsp70l:EGFP+)","Tg(hsp70l:EGFP+)","Tg(hsp70l:EGFP+)","Tg(hsp70l:EGFP+)","Tg(hsp70l:EGFP+)","Tg(hsp70l:EGFP+)","Tg(hsp70l:EGFP+)","Tg(hsp70l:EGFP+)","Tg(hsp70l:EGFP+)","Tg(hsp70l:EGFP+)","Tg(hsp70l:EGFP+)","Tg(hsp70l:EGFP+)","Tg(hsp70l:EGFP+)"),
    subject = c(401,402,403,404,405,406,407,408,409,410,411,412,413,414,415,416,417,418,419,420,421,422,423,424,425,426,427,428,429,430,431,432,433,434,435,436,437,438,439,440,441,442,443,444,445,446,447,448,449,450,451,452,453,454,455,456,457,458,459,460,461,462,463,464,465,466,467,468,469,470,471,472,473,474,475,476,477,478,479,480,481,482,483,484,485,486,487,488,489,490,491,492,493,494,495,496,497,498,499,500,501,502,503,504,505,506,507,508,509,510,511,512,513,514,515,516,517,518,519,520,521,522,523,524,525,526,527,528,529,530,531,532,533,534,535,536,537,538,539,540,541,542,543,544,545,546,547,548,549,550,551,552,553,554,555,556,557,558,559,560,561,562,563,564,565,566,567,568,569,570,571,572,573,574,575,576,577,578,579,580,581,582,583,584,585,586,587,588,589,590,591,592,593,594,595,596,597,598,599,600),
    acclimation = c("Q4","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q1","Q1","Q3","Q1","Q2","Q1","Q4","Q3","Q3","Q3","Q2","Q3","Q4","Q3","Q2","Q2","Q2","Q3","Q4","Q1","Q3","Q3","Q4","Q3","Q3","Q1","Q2","Q4","Q4","Q2","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q2","Q2","Q2","Q1","Q4","Q3","Q1","Q2","Q2","Q4","Q3","Q2","Q4","Q2","Q1","Q1","Q2","Q1","Q2","Q1","Q3","Q1","Q3","Q1","Q4","Q1","Q2","Q3","Q2","Q1","Q1","Q1","Q4","Q2","Q3","Q4","Q3","Q2","Q2","Q4","Q1","Q2","Q1","Q1","Q2","Q2","Q2","Q4","Q1","Q3","Q2","Q3","Q3","Q1","Q3","Q1","Q4","Q1","Q3","Q1","Q2","Q1","Q4","Q1","Q3","Q1","Q1","Q2","Q1","Q2","Q2","Q1","Q1","Q4","Q4","Q1","Q4","Q2","Q2","Q4","Q1","Q1","Q4","Q3","Q4","Q4","Q3","Q4","Q2","Q1","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q3","Q1","Q4","Q2","Q4","Q1","Q3","Q2","Q2","Q1","Q3","Q1","Q4","Q1","Q4","Q1","Q1","Q3","Q4","Q4","Q3","Q3","Q4","Q1","Q2","Q1","Q4","Q1","Q3","Q1","Q4","Q3","Q1","Q4","Q4","Q1","Q2","Q1","Q1","Q3","Q1","Q3","Q1","Q3","Q4","Q1","Q3","Q3","Q4","Q1","Q4","Q2","Q3","Q1","Q2","Q4","Q2","Q1","Q3","Q2","Q1","Q3","Q2","Q3","Q2","Q3","Q4"),
    grating_1 = c("Q4","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q1","Q1","Q4","Q3","Q4","Q1","Q4","Q4","Q3","Q3","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q2","Q1","Q1","Q4","Q4","Q2","Q1","Q3","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q1","Q4","Q4","Q1","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q2","Q4","Q2","Q1","Q4","Q3","Q1","Q2","Q2","Q4","Q4","Q2","Q3","Q1","Q1","Q1","Q2","Q1","Q2","Q3","Q4","Q4","Q1","Q4","Q4","Q1","Q3","Q4","Q4","Q1","Q1","Q1","Q4","Q2","Q4","Q4","Q3","Q2","Q1","Q4","Q2","Q2","Q2","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q2","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q2","Q3","Q4","Q4","Q3","Q4","Q4","Q1","Q2","Q1","Q4","Q1","Q4","Q1","Q3","Q2","Q1","Q1","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q3","Q1","Q4","Q1","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q1","Q1","Q3","Q3","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q3","Q1","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q1","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q1","Q4","Q1","Q2","Q3","Q3","Q4","Q4","Q1","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q3","Q4","Q1","Q1","Q4","Q2","Q4","Q1","Q4","Q3","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q3","Q4","Q1","Q1","Q4","Q3","Q3","Q1","Q3","Q4","Q2","Q4","Q3","Q1","Q1","Q4","Q2","Q4","Q1","Q4","Q4","Q2","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q2","Q4","Q4","Q3","Q2","Q4","Q3"),
    grating_2 = c("Q1","Q1","Q1","Q1","Q4","Q4","Q1","Q3","Q1","Q4","Q4","Q1","Q2","Q4","Q3","Q4","Q1","Q1","Q4","Q3","Q4","Q4","Q1","Q3","Q3","Q2","Q4","Q1","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q1","Q1","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q1","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q3","Q4","Q1","Q2","Q3","Q3","Q3","Q1","Q1","Q3","Q1","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q3","Q4","Q1","Q3","Q2","Q2","Q1","Q4","Q1","Q2","Q1","Q1","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q3","Q4","Q1","Q2","Q3","Q4","Q1","Q3","Q3","Q3","Q4","Q3","Q1","Q3","Q3","Q4","Q4","Q3","Q4","Q1","Q1","Q2","Q4","Q1","Q3","Q4","Q3","Q1","Q3","Q2","Q4","Q2","Q4","Q4","Q3","Q2","Q1","Q1","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q1","Q4","Q1","Q3","Q1","Q1","Q4","Q4","Q1","Q4","Q1","Q1","Q4","Q2","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q1","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q1","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q2","Q2","Q4","Q4","Q1","Q3","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q1","Q4","Q4","Q1","Q4","Q4","Q3","Q1","Q2","Q3","Q1","Q2","Q4","Q1","Q3","Q1","Q1","Q4","Q4","Q1","Q4","Q2","Q4","Q2","Q2","Q4","Q2","Q2","Q4","Q4","Q1","Q1","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q1","Q3","Q4","Q3","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q2","Q4","Q4","Q3"),
    grating_3 = c("Q4","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q1","Q1","Q4","Q3","Q4","Q1","Q4","Q4","Q3","Q2","Q4","Q1","Q4","Q4","Q1","Q4","Q1","Q4","Q4","Q2","Q4","Q3","Q1","Q4","Q4","Q1","Q2","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q2","Q4","Q2","Q1","Q4","Q3","Q4","Q1","Q2","Q4","Q4","Q2","Q4","Q1","Q1","Q1","Q4","Q1","Q2","Q1","Q4","Q2","Q1","Q2","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q3","Q3","Q4","Q1","Q4","Q1","Q2","Q2","Q4","Q4","Q2","Q4","Q4","Q2","Q2","Q2","Q4","Q2","Q4","Q2","Q3","Q4","Q4","Q2","Q1","Q4","Q4","Q2","Q4","Q4","Q1","Q3","Q1","Q4","Q1","Q1","Q1","Q3","Q1","Q1","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q1","Q1","Q1","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q2","Q4","Q4","Q1","Q1","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q3","Q2","Q1","Q3","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q1","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q1","Q1","Q1","Q1","Q4","Q1","Q3","Q2","Q1","Q1","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q1","Q1","Q1","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q1","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q3","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q1","Q1","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q1","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q3","Q1","Q1","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q1","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q1","Q2","Q4","Q3","Q4","Q1","Q1"),
    grating_4 = c("Q1","Q2","Q1","Q1","Q4","Q4","Q2","Q2","Q1","Q4","Q2","Q1","Q2","Q3","Q1","Q4","Q1","Q1","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q2","Q1","Q3","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q1","Q1","Q4","Q2","Q1","Q1","Q1","Q1","Q4","Q1","Q4","Q3","Q4","Q3","Q4","Q1","Q2","Q1","Q4","Q3","Q1","Q1","Q3","Q1","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q1","Q4","Q1","Q4","Q2","Q2","Q1","Q1","Q1","Q2","Q2","Q4","Q4","Q1","Q4","Q1","Q4","Q1","Q3","Q3","Q4","Q1","Q3","Q3","Q3","Q4","Q3","Q1","Q3","Q2","Q3","Q4","Q3","Q4","Q1","Q1","Q2","Q3","Q1","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q2","Q1","Q1","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q1","Q1","Q1","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q1","Q1","Q1","Q3","Q1","Q1","Q4","Q4","Q3","Q1","Q3","Q4","Q3","Q2","Q2","Q4","Q2","Q4","Q1","Q2","Q4","Q2","Q2","Q1","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q1","Q4","Q2","Q1","Q4","Q4","Q1","Q4","Q1","Q4","Q2","Q3","Q1","Q3","Q1","Q1","Q2","Q4","Q3","Q1","Q1","Q3","Q1","Q1","Q1","Q1","Q1","Q1","Q1","Q4","Q4","Q1","Q4","Q2","Q4","Q4","Q2","Q4","Q2","Q2","Q4","Q4","Q1","Q1","Q3","Q1","Q3","Q1","Q1","Q1","Q3","Q4","Q4","Q3","Q2","Q2","Q1","Q4","Q3"),
    grating_5 = c("Q4","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q1","Q1","Q4","Q3","Q4","Q1","Q3","Q4","Q3","Q2","Q4","Q1","Q4","Q4","Q1","Q1","Q2","Q4","Q4","Q2","Q3","Q3","Q2","Q4","Q4","Q1","Q3","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q2","Q4","Q2","Q1","Q4","Q3","Q4","Q1","Q2","Q4","Q4","Q2","Q4","Q1","Q1","Q1","Q1","Q1","Q4","Q1","Q4","Q2","Q2","Q4","Q4","Q3","Q3","Q1","Q4","Q1","Q1","Q1","Q4","Q2","Q3","Q4","Q3","Q2","Q2","Q4","Q2","Q2","Q2","Q4","Q2","Q4","Q2","Q3","Q1","Q4","Q3","Q1","Q4","Q4","Q3","Q3","Q4","Q2","Q1","Q1","Q3","Q1","Q4","Q1","Q1","Q1","Q1","Q3","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q1","Q1","Q1","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q2","Q4","Q4","Q1","Q1","Q3","Q2","Q3","Q4","Q3","Q3","Q3","Q1","Q3","Q3","Q4","Q2","Q1","Q1","Q3","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q2","Q1","Q1","Q4","Q1","Q3","Q1","Q1","Q1","Q4","Q4","Q2","Q1","Q4","Q2","Q4","Q3","Q4","Q4","Q1","Q1","Q2","Q4","Q4","Q3","Q4","Q4","Q1","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q1","Q1","Q4","Q1","Q4","Q1","Q1","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q3","Q1","Q1","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q1","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q3","Q4","Q1","Q3","Q1","Q3","Q4","Q1","Q2"),
    grating_6 = c("Q1","Q3","Q1","Q1","Q4","Q4","Q1","Q2","Q1","Q4","Q2","Q1","Q1","Q3","Q1","Q4","Q1","Q1","Q4","Q4","Q3","Q1","Q1","Q3","Q1","Q2","Q2","Q1","Q1","Q3","Q1","Q1","Q1","Q3","Q1","Q4","Q1","Q2","Q1","Q4","Q3","Q4","Q1","Q2","Q1","Q4","Q3","Q1","Q1","Q3","Q2","Q1","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q2","Q4","Q1","Q2","Q2","Q3","Q1","Q2","Q2","Q2","Q4","Q1","Q4","Q1","Q1","Q1","Q2","Q1","Q2","Q3","Q4","Q1","Q3","Q3","Q3","Q2","Q2","Q1","Q3","Q2","Q4","Q2","Q3","Q1","Q1","Q1","Q2","Q3","Q1","Q3","Q4","Q4","Q2","Q4","Q1","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q2","Q1","Q2","Q1","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q1","Q1","Q1","Q3","Q1","Q1","Q4","Q4","Q2","Q3","Q1","Q4","Q2","Q3","Q2","Q4","Q2","Q3","Q1","Q4","Q4","Q1","Q4","Q1","Q3","Q2","Q3","Q4","Q2","Q1","Q4","Q2","Q1","Q1","Q4","Q1","Q1","Q4","Q4","Q1","Q3","Q1","Q2","Q1","Q1","Q1","Q4","Q1","Q1","Q1","Q3","Q1","Q1","Q1","Q1","Q1","Q3","Q1","Q4","Q4","Q1","Q4","Q1","Q4","Q4","Q1","Q1","Q2","Q2","Q4","Q4","Q1","Q1","Q4","Q4","Q2","Q1","Q1","Q1","Q2","Q2","Q4","Q2","Q2","Q2","Q1","Q3","Q4"),
    grating_7 = c("Q4","Q2","Q4","Q4","Q1","Q1","Q3","Q2","Q4","Q1","Q2","Q4","Q3","Q2","Q4","Q1","Q4","Q4","Q1","Q2","Q1","Q3","Q4","Q2","Q1","Q3","Q2","Q4","Q1","Q1","Q2","Q4","Q4","Q2","Q4","Q2","Q4","Q3","Q2","Q2","Q2","Q1","Q4","Q3","Q4","Q1","Q2","Q2","Q4","Q2","Q3","Q1","Q1","Q3","Q1","Q1","Q1","Q1","Q4","Q3","Q1","Q2","Q4","Q3","Q3","Q3","Q4","Q4","Q1","Q4","Q3","Q4","Q2","Q4","Q3","Q2","Q1","Q4","Q2","Q2","Q2","Q1","Q3","Q4","Q2","Q3","Q2","Q2","Q2","Q3","Q4","Q4","Q3","Q1","Q4","Q3","Q1","Q1","Q3","Q1","Q4","Q1","Q1","Q2","Q1","Q3","Q4","Q3","Q4","Q1","Q1","Q1","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q2","Q4","Q4","Q1","Q1","Q3","Q1","Q3","Q1","Q3","Q2","Q3","Q1","Q1","Q1","Q4","Q4","Q1","Q1","Q1","Q4","Q4","Q3","Q2","Q1","Q1","Q3","Q2","Q3","Q1","Q2","Q1","Q4","Q4","Q3","Q1","Q1","Q2","Q4","Q2","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q1","Q3","Q4","Q4","Q2","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q2","Q4","Q1","Q1","Q4","Q1","Q3","Q1","Q1","Q3","Q4","Q3","Q3","Q1","Q1","Q4","Q3","Q1","Q1","Q3","Q4","Q4","Q4","Q2","Q1","Q1","Q1","Q1","Q3","Q4","Q2","Q3"),
    age = c("5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF","5 DPF"),
    body_pigment = c("b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","m","m","m","m","m","m","m","m","m","m","m","m","m","m","m","m","m","m","m","m","m","m","m","m","m","m","m","m","m","m","m","m","m","m","m","m","m","m","m","m","i","i","i","i","i","i","i","i","i","i","i","i","i","i","i","i","i","i","i","i","i","i","i","i","i","i","i","i","i","i","i","i","i","i","i","i","i","i","i","i","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b"),
    transgene = c("n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","y","y","y","y","y","y","y","y","y","y","y","y","y","y","y","y","y","y","y","y","y","y","y","y","y","y","y","y","y","y","y","y","y","y","y","y","y","y","y","y")),
    row.names = c(NA,-200L),class = c("tbl_df","tbl","data.frame"))

I am not sure where to go from here and would appreciate the help!

body_pigment is declared as a factor variable and frequency_pigment as a continuous variable (and the dependent variable is OMRResponse which is binary), so the glmer summary table looks correct. Can you clarify what's the error? Also, the data prep steps are difficult (impossible?) to follow without the data.

Thank you for your help, I  have added the data needed to run the code. I  can't add the data for the other age groups due to character limitations, so I hope that this helps. The error, or what I think is the error, is that multiple factors for body pigment (m and n) are populating in the summary table.

Thanks a lot for the data, it's helpful. In hindsight I realize I should have given some instructions on how to attach data when working in R. There are several ways to provide data, probably adding the output of dput(<yourData>) or dput(head(<yourData>)) is easiest. I edited your question this way for readability. (I read the markdown with read_delim and converted it to text with dput.)

Okay, I can reproduce the glmer summary. There are two rows for body_pigment because this variable has three levels in data (m, b, n). One level -- b -- is the reference level and is "incorporated" into the (Intercept). Isn't this intended? Can you explain in words how you mean to translate your research question about the pigments in terms of the body_pigment  and frequency_pigment variables?

I   am working with different strains of zebrafish that present different levels of pigmentation in their skin. In this particular question, we are working with 5-day-old fish and focusing only on melanophores. We want to see if differences in pigmentation affect visual acuity. We test visual acuity with the optomotor response assay (frequency_pigment), and the three strains of fish have either both pigments, neither pigment, or one of the pigment types. I  am hoping this summary will confirm there are differences in visual acuity in relation to the difference in pigment in these strains

I  do not understand why having the different pigment levels shown in the summary table would be an issue. I thought both being present in this table would show significance in having neither pigment or just the pigment of interest (melanophores). This is how I   have been advised by my direct supervisor and I   am hoping to gain some clarity on where I  might be misinformed.

All fish of the same strain have the same body_pigment. Each fish has 7 data points with frequency_pigment = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 corresponding to the sevent gratings. The ratings vary from 1 to 4 but right now OMRResponse is set to 1 if the rating is Q4 and 0 otherwise?
So if I understand correctly the gratings are something like increasing visual acuity, and then OMRResponse indicates whether the fish had this level of acuity or not?

I suggest that one good place to start is to come up with a nice plot of the data? Perhaps that can confirm (or not) your expectations and help to clarify what the model might look like?

This is work in progress as the OP hasn't yet fully clarified why the GLMM output is incorrect. What I've done so far is to simplify the data wrangling steps (fewer steps, fewer opportunities to make mistakes), and to make a plot of the data being analyzed with the GLMM (understanding the data better can help to choose and improve the model).
I use R and the {tidyverse} collection of packages.
library("lme4")
library("tidyverse")

melanophore_OMR_5dpf <- LarvalOMRPigment1 |>
  # Choose the age group (5-day-old zerbrafish) and the strains.
  filter(
    strain %in% c("Roy", "Casper", "AB"),
    age == "5 DPF"
  ) |>
  # Simplify by omitting the data on acclimation.
  select(
    -acclimation
  ) |>
  # To begin with, the seven ratings are reported in seven different columns.
  # "Pivot" these columns, so that the rating are reported in different rows
  # instead. Also parse the column names to extract the pigment frequency
  # (which ranges from 1 to 7) and the values to extract the rating
  # (which ranges from 1 to 4).
  pivot_longer(
    grating_1:grating_7,
    names_to = "frequency_pigment",
    names_transform = \(x) parse_number(x),
    values_to = "rating",
    values_transform = \(x) parse_number(x)
  ) |>
  # The response is 1 if the rating is 4 (denoted Q4 in the original data)
  # and 0 otherwise.
  mutate(
    OMRResponse = if_else(rating == 4, 1L, 0L)
  )

Let's check that we get the same GLMM output as before. It's still unclear though why this output is unexpected and/or incorrect.
melanophore_OMR_5dpf_glmer <- glmer(
  OMRResponse ~ body_pigment * frequency_pigment + (frequency_pigment | subject),
  data = melanophore_OMR_5dpf,
  family = binomial
)
#> Random effects:
#>  Groups  Name              Variance  Std.Dev. Corr 
#>  subject (Intercept)       0.2849230 0.53378       
#>          frequency_pigment 0.0002295 0.01515  -1.00
#> Number of obs: 840, groups:  subject, 120
#> 
#> Fixed effects:
#>                                 Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
#> (Intercept)                      0.69911    0.29486   2.371 0.017741 *  
#> body_pigmentm                   -0.62917    0.41502  -1.516 0.129522    
#> body_pigmentn                   -1.24174    0.42449  -2.925 0.003442 ** 
#> frequency_pigment               -0.22549    0.06440  -3.501 0.000463 ***
#> body_pigmentm:frequency_pigment  0.09180    0.09048   1.015 0.310338    
#> body_pigmentn:frequency_pigment  0.16353    0.09223   1.773 0.076220 .  

The three zebrafish strains have different body pigment.
melanophore_OMR_5dpf |>
  count(
    strain, body_pigment
  )
#> A tibble: 3 × 3
#>   strain body_pigment     n
#>   <chr>  <chr>        <int>
#> 1 AB     b              280
#> 2 Casper n              280
#> 3 Roy    m              280

Let's calculate and visualize the strains' average rating at each pigment frequency. The average rating on the y-axis is plotted against the pigment frequency on the x-axis and for clarity each strain is shown in different color.
melanophore_OMR_5dpf |>
  group_by(
    strain, body_pigment, frequency_pigment
  ) |>
  summarise(
    rating = mean(rating)
  ) |>
  ggplot(
    aes(frequency_pigment, rating, color = strain)
  ) +
  geom_line() +
  labs(
    x = "pigment frequency",
    title = "Experimental data on zebrafish pigmentation and visual acuity"
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(
    limits = c(2, 3.5)
  ) +
  theme(
    plot.title = element_text(size = 18)
  )


That's how far I've gotten with the information provided. My next step would be to double check the ratings of the AB strain. The zigzag pattern seems unexpected?

Thank you for your help, I believe that there is nothing wrong with the model but it was the feedback that I was getting from my supervisor that was pushing me to believe that I was making errors along the way. The zigzag pattern is a result of side bias in the behavioral assessment we are giving the fish. The line loses this pattern at the older ages. I appreciate your support as it helped me to defend my data and is allowing me to move forward.

Great, thanks for the update. I'm glad the validation of the data prep/analysis was helpful. @EdM's suggestions for potential next steps for the modeling are worth following up too. Good luck with your research!

Looking at the data, as in the answer by @dipetkov (+1), is always a good idea. A few more observations follow.
First, if you are just starting out with this type of analysis, it's easy to get confused by what's reported in a model summary. It doesn't directly represent an overall estimate of the association of a multi-level categorical predictor (factor) with outcome. With a categorical predictor and the default "dummy" or "treatment" coding used in R, the (Intercept) represents the estimated outcome at the reference level of the predictor. You then get 1 coefficient for each of the non-reference levels, representing the difference from the outcome at the reference predictor level.
Thus, to answer what I interpret to be the question embedded in your title, if

in this group of fish, three out of the four pigment types will be present in the data set; m = only melanophores, b = both pigment types, and n = neither pigment type

then necessarily your "fixed effects are being split into multiple factors," both for the individual coefficients and for the interactions. Your body_pigment predictor in a model is a categorical predictor with 3 levels, so you get 2 coefficients for body_pigment and 2 corresponding coefficients for each interaction involving body_pigment. You have body_pigment = "b" as the reference level (incorporated in the intercept), with body_pigmentm and body_pigmentn representing estmated differences from the outcome at the reference level.
Second, it is possible to get a combined evaluation of the significance of all levels of the predictor combined. That seems to be what you are expecting. That won't come out of the basic model summary that you show, however. You need to do extra post-model processing to get that.
For a categorical predictor that's often done with some flavor of an "anova()" function. The Anova() function in the R car package is one good choice. Avoid the anova() or aov() functions in the basic R distribution, as by default they use a "Type I" analysis that isn't very useful unless the data are perfectly balanced. Read the help page for the Anova() function in the car package for the interpretation of the Type II and Type III analyses provided. They test different types of hypotheses when there are interactions and unbalanced designs, so you have to think about which hypothesis you want to test.
What can be even more useful is to evaluate model predictions at a set of representative predictor values and determine how much those predictions differ as a function of predictor values. The emmeans package is a frequent choice for that.
Third, I worry that you are throwing away useful data by breaking down your 4-level (?) outcome response_ac variable into just two categories depending on whether it has a value of 4. This might be handled better by an ordinal regression model that uses all the levels of the outcome.
Fourth, you might be getting into some trouble by using a random slope, the (frequency_pigment5dpf |  subject) term in the models. You might not have enough observations per individual to handle a random slope properly. Consider whether you really think that the association of frequency_pigment5dpf with outcome is likely to differ so much among individuals of the same strain that you require random slope terms to account for that. Random intercepts provide at least some ability to account for correlations within individuals.
Finally, you might be better off with a large, comprehensive model including all of your data rather than breaking the data up into subsets based on age and strain. You would then include age and strain as predictors in the model, possibly including interactions with one or more of the other predictors (depending on your understanding of the subject matter). That can end up providing more power than your subsetting.

Thank you very much! you have given me a lot to process and have made it easier to understand where I  am in terms of interpreting the data. I    can provide a some more information if that helps to clarify why some things were done the way that they were.
First, acclimation and optomotor response had to be separated because the acclimation period was reducing the differences between the strains. we also find this to be more appropriate as there is no stimulus being presented during the acclimation period

Our score system remains the same for both omr scores and acclimation scores because it is based on the fish's position in their observation lane. During acclimation, we assume no difference to be found between the strains because their likelihood of being in the target area should be as likely as being in any of the quadrants. However, there should be differences in frequency of being in the target quadrant when the visual stimulus is presented. Differences between strains should be observed if differences in pigmentation affect visual acuity.
